# Research Assistance OR What Do I Google? - .service is no longer starting

Tags: docker

So I'm asking specifically how I'd go about debugging this issue on my own. I've found my knowledge to be lacking here, so links to articles would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to install SearXNG on a server with docker (I've successfully done this a dozen times or so but keep tinkering until it breaks or I lock myself out). So I've created my own step-by-step guide so I can recreate the server easier. This time I got a error that I haven't come across before. it was an exit code:

```
● searxng-docker.service - SearXNG service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/searxng-docker/searxng-docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-06-26 14:32:59 UTC; 22min ago
    Process: 966 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f ${SEARXNG_DOCKERCOMPOSEFILE} up --remove-orphans (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 966 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 633us

Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[966]: searxng-docker.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: searxng-docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: searxng-docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: searxng-docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: Stopped SearXNG service.
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: searxng-docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: searxng-docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[1]: Failed to start SearXNG service.
```

I thought I understood this because the /usr/local/bin/   directory is empty. So I edited the searxng-docker.service and pointed it to: /usr/local/searxng-docker/  but that didn't work and I got a new error. So I checked that file against my working SearXNG server, and it points to the empty /usr/local/bin/  directory.

So I removed my searxng-docker folder and re-cloned it from github.

Now it's not working but also isn't showing up in the services after calling *docker-compose up -d*:

```
searxngadmin@SearXNG-Debian:/usr/local/searxng-docker$ sudo service --status-all
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ - ]  cgroupfs-mount
 [ + ]  chrony
 [ + ]  cloud-config
 [ + ]  cloud-final
 [ + ]  cloud-init
 [ + ]  cloud-init-local
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  docker
 [ + ]  fail2ban
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  networking
 [ + ]  procps
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
```

Any links you can point me to to fill in the gaps in my knowledge would be helpful. I'm not getting anything useful with my google searches and I don't know how to go about debugging this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: `Jun 26 14:32:59 SearXNG-Debian systemd[966]: searxng-docker.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory`. Locate that step in your .service file (or whatever script it launches). Edit that step to point to the correct `docker-compose` location.